# How to make a component fit parents width using BoxLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have JPanel with BoxLayout Y-Axis and want to add multiple JLabels to this Panel. The Labels should fit the Panels width but only use the height they need to. Can one of you help me?

Comment: By default `BoxLayout` respects the `preferredSize` of the components, you should use another layout instead like `GridLayout` for example or wrap each line of your `BoxLayout` inside a `FlowLayout`. But for better help sooner, please post a [mcve] and an image or ascii art of your actual and desired output in minimal size and if resizable with extra space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is how it looks like when I use GridLayout: http://prntscr.com/e74ftl , because I don't know how many labels there will be when the user is using it. And this is how it looks with BoxLayout: http://prntscr.com/e74gr0 , but I want the labels to be as the panel they're in and not just as big as they need to be to display their string.

Comment: @Frakcool, `By default BoxLayout respects the preferredSize of the components,` - actually in this case BoxLayout respects the maximum size of the component. Normally a BoxLayout will allow components to grow when there is extra space. However, the preferred and maximum size of a JLabel are the same so the label will never grow to fill the available space.

Comment: @camickr true, I missread and got confused with `JLabel` and `JTextField`, but you're right :) thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to make a component fit parents width using BoxLayout?

A BoxLayout respects the `maximum size` size of a component. For a `JLabel` the preferred and maximum sizes are the same so the label doesn't grow in size.

So you could override the the `getMaximumSize()` method of each JLabel to do something like:

```
return new Dimension(getPreferredSize().width, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

However an easier approach is to nsting panels to ive you the effect you need.

For example:

```
JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
labelPanel.add(new JLabel( "one" ) );
labelPanel.add(new JLabel( "two" ) );

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
wrapper.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now the labelPanel will take only the height it needs but the width will grow to fill the width of the frame and therefore the labels width will also grow.

Another option, without using nested panels is to use the `GridBagLayout`. It supports a `fill` constraint which will allow each component to resize to fill the space available.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very very much! This one helped me. Never had to with minimumSize and maximumSize of components before.